# Android - Custom made spell checker

Tags: android

I'm wondering if its possible to create a custom spell checker that other apps will use when they request spell checking.

The setting is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQeA7.jpg

On my current phone, there are 2, Htc's own spell checker and googles. This led me to wonder if its possible to create my own.

I understand it would never be as good as the existing ones, but for some situations, a fully custom spell checker could be useful.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Its a good idea to check these **useful and well-designed spell checker libraries**.

1) spell-check-android ([link](https://github.com/emuneee/spell-check-android))

2) HelloSpellChecker ([link](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SpellChecker/HelloSpellChecker))

3) AndroidHunspellService ([link](https://github.com/mweimerskirch/AndroidHunspellService))

4) Spell Checker ([link](https://github.com/shyam057cs/Spell-Checker))

5) Android's Spelling Checker Framework ([link](https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-SpellingCheckerFramework))

If you are in a hurry, you can directly use them in your project (just remember to give proper credit) or you can see how these libraries have been developed. These samples can help you a lot learn and implement it yourself. **Learn the best from all**.